# Looping background color with array and for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, background

I am trying to loop the colors, and I am not getting this code correct. It is going to the last color. Not sure what I am doing wrong, I must be missing a line or something.

```
var forum = $('.main-content .statused tr'),i;
 var colors = ["#000","#F00","#FF0","#FFF","#0F0","#00F"];
    for(var j=0;j<forum.length;j++) {
       forumBG= forum[parseInt(j)];
       if(!forumBG) return;

  for (i=0;i<colors.length; i++){
   forum[j].style.background =colors[i];

  }
 }
```

Can anyone help me figure out the loop through different colored backgrounds?

Comment: What color should get assigned?  Your looping through all the colors so it sets the background equal to them in each iteration ending on the last color which is the final color set.

Comment: Yeah that is what is happening. I want each TR to have a different color and if there are more than (6) tr's it will go back to the beginning of the array. so basically each tr will have a different BG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var forum = $('.main-content .statused tr'),i;
var colors = ["#000","#F00","#FF0","#FFF","#0F0","#00F"];
var i = 0;

 for(var j=0;j<forum.length;j++) {
     forumBG= forum[j];

     if(!forumBG) return;

     forum[j].style.background =colors[i];

     if(i == colors.length -1){
          i= 0;
     }else{
          i++;
     }
 }
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/LMdXn/

Comment: Thank you so much Kevin Bowersox! so basically I only needed one for loop, and an if else statement? I just like to know how the code works for future reference and so I can actually know how to do this instead of just a code given to me :)